In what movie does a scientist wake up in a WWII bunker with demons in 1944?
The movie starts out with a scientist waking up and having no memory during WWII in a secret underground bunker.  Then a black scientist with glasses tells him about the demons that rip off their shirts and vomit on victims' mouths/faces; they sort marinate, then turn and chase.  Two armed guys outside are trying to protect the bunker from outside but mainly INSIDE threats.  The scientists find tests in a room & diary of portal with symbols that are also on a wall.  The demons are ripping people up everywhere.  The diary said it was a portal to get infinite power forever.  But it's really a cult portal that brings in a VERY large planet-eating demon that's round with tons of tentacles.

If you're asking about two distinct movies, this should be two distinct questions.

Is this one movie with two distinct segments that seem to combine at the very end? Or are you asking about two specific movies? Also, you mention Russian soldiers. What language were the movies in? Do you remember where you saw the movie , such as a particular streaming site?

sounds like so many 'war in a bunker turns horrific' movies that were a trend for a while... probably because a lot of cold war bunkers were being sold off or being opened up at the time, i guess... 'ooh, no ones ever shot in a cold war bunker before..'
